# sql 2000 trace : sp_releaseschemalock

Tags: sql-server-2000, profiler

For a SQL 2000 server, is it bad to see too many

> exec sp_releaseschemalock 1

events in a SQL trace file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sp_releaseschemalock is an internal stored procedure, under normal circumstances, seeing many of it is not an issue.